# Android BottomNavigationView tint icon color

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I'm using `BottomNavigationView`and I've set colors like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_navigation_height"
    app:itemBackground="@color/white"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_bar_item_selector"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_bar_item_selector"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
```

@color/bottom_bar_item_selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
    <item android:color="@color/grey" />
</selector>
```

[image: BottomNavigationBar]

The problem is, that my `@color/colorPrimary` is `#C4071A`, but final selected item color is lighter (`#E65A6E`). The difference is visible on the screenshot - icon color is lighter then the text color. Is there a way how to use exactly same color?

@menu/bottom_navigation_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar_item_one"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_1"
        android:title="item1"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:enabled="true" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar_item_two"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_2"
        android:title="item2"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:enabled="true" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar_item_three"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_3"
        android:title="item3"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:enabled="true" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar_item_four"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_4"
        android:title="item4"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:enabled="true" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/bottom_bar_item_five"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_5"
        android:title="item5"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:enabled="true" />
</menu>
```

Note I'm using Xamarin, but since I'm using native `BottomNavigationView` I wouldn't expect any difference.

Comment: First guess is that there's an alpha channel applied to the icons

Comment: @BenP. There isn't, I've added items layout, all drawables are PNGs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your png files seems to have an alpha channel/transparency

I checked your both `checked` and `uncheck` states of icons.

**Your grey colored icons also have the same problem as red ones.** If you open these png files with Adobe Photoshop etc, you can see that channel by adding solid white colored layer under the icon (if the alpha cannel is active).

[image]

Comment: Indeed you're right. Just removed alpha in GIMP and it looks as desired now. Thanks!