# Error when inflating Bottom Navigation View

Tags: android, android-studio, bottomnavigationview

**It works fine in my phone of API 27, but crashes in API22**

**here is the xml file**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ReportsActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/bgBottomNavigation"
    app:itemBackground="@color/bgBottomNavigation"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_color"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_color"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

**Here is MainActivity file**

CoordinatorLayout container;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reports);

    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    requestPermission();


    loadFragment(new BranchVisitFragment());
}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menuLogout:

            FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));

            break;

        case R.id.refresh:

            Fragment f = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container);
            if( f instanceof BranchVisitFragment)
                BranchVisitFragment.refresh();
            if(f instanceof GroupFragment)
                GroupFragment.refresh();
            break;

        case R.id.excel:

            Toast.makeText(this,"Creating the Excel Sheet...",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            CreateExcel.createExcel();
            break;
```

**I feel the error is due to this file, but I don't know how to make both the things work properly in API22**

Here is nav_color.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="#039BE5" />
    <item android:color="#616161"  />
</selector>
```

**I have looked into stackoverflow for possible solutions but I am unable to find one**

This is the gradle file

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

This is the error:

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #16: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:637)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:747)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:508)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:418)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
    at com.example.aditya.pdf_report.ReportsActivity.onCreate(ReportsActivity.java:59)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6093)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1315) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5296) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:611)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:747) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:508) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:418) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
    at com.example.aditya.pdf_report.ReportsActivity.onCreate(ReportsActivity.java:59) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6093) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2404) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1315) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5296) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:707) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f070087
    at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1313)
    at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getValue(MiuiResources.java:146)
    at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.isColorInt(AppCompatResources.java:163)
    at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.inflateColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:110)
    at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:76)
    at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getColorStateList(TintTypedArray.java:171)
    at android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:148)
    at android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:114)
```

Line 16 in XML

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
```

Line 59 in Activity

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_reports);
```

colors.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#1F618D</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#000</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#D81B60</color>
    <color name="bgBottomNavigation">#fff</color>
    <color name="activated">#039BE5</color>
    <color name="notactive">#616161</color>

</resources>
```

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menuLogout"
    android:title="Logout" />

<item
    android:title=""
    android:id="@+id/refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ref"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/excel"
    android:title="Create Excel"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

Comment: what is error??

Comment: @PankajKumar  I have update the error

Comment: have you tried to run the code on api 22 withou `nav_color.xml` file?

Comment: @victorldavila yes, it was working just fine before I added that

Comment: I think your error is that `@color/nav_color` you have to add the file nav_color.xml inside the drawable folder and then add `@drawable/nav_color` in these fields that you are having problems.

Comment: @victorldavila I have tried that, the attribute android:itemiconTint  doesn't take anything from Drawable folder

Comment: have you looked this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45397191/android-bottomnavigationview-tint-icon-color

Comment: Please post the whole error logs along with the layout and drawables. Also, make sure, there are not multiple layouts.

Comment: @victorldavila it seems like my problem, but how can we remove that, I don't have photoshop.

Comment: @MohammedsalimShivani I have updated the entire error stack.

Comment: What's in line #16 in XML file and line #59 in `ReportsActivity.java`??

Comment: @MohammedsalimShivani  I have update from where those lines come from

Comment: I guess, you have more than 1 xml for `ActivityReports` for different versions or orientations.

Comment: @MohammedsalimShivani I have just one XML working for this, I don't think this is the answer.

Comment: And what about `colors.xml` and `menu.xml` used in navigation?

Comment: @MohammedsalimShivani Updated them

Comment: There's no value with #id `nav_color` in `colors.xml`

Comment: @MohammedsalimShivani nav_color is an xml file as I have written. It's a selector file. I have followed one of the accepted answers on Stackoverflow where it was implemeted this way.

Comment: Try `android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"` in your layout.

Comment: @MohammedsalimShivani it's already there

Comment: `android` is not there after `?`. Please add and try it.

Comment: @MohammedsalimShivani sorry for the previous time, i added it but still the same

Comment: Then try deleting the `.idea` and `build` folder in your root directory. And reload the project.

Comment: @MohammedsalimShivani No, Tried it, still the same. the irritating part is that it worked without nav_color but now even when I remove it again, it's still not working

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After 12 hours of rigorous thought and thinking, I finally found the solution.

Absolutely nothing was wrong with my code.

It was in the drawable folder.

I put 2 icon PNGs in v24 drawable folder as a result of which it wasn't working for API23 and API22 where I checked.

So just put them back in Drawable folder and it works like a charm.

Thank You everyone for help.

Comment: @MohammedsalimShivani   Sure. Actually, Stack Overflow allows accepting self-answers after 36 hrs of answering.

Comment: Upvoting. I inherited this, and it took me couple of hours to figure out - thanks for this post.

Answer (score 1):

bottom navigation was added in api 26
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView

Comment: It certainly does appear from the link, but just yesterday, when I didn't add the nav_color.xml file, it was working just fine. SO this is certainly NOT the answer

Comment: Accd. to this link it is supported till API 14 https://stackoverflow.com/a/51464819/10485139

Comment: i don't see where they see 14 in any of those links.

Comment: Your link is about `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView`. It's WRONG

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved by removing the style attribute from the bottom navigation view xml.

`style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView"`

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the version in bottom navigation gradle implementation and again manually added navigation bar in xml file and assigned all attributes. It Worked